# basic shell programming

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Probably this is a very basic question for shell programmers.
But suppose I have a text file A and B
and B is a subset of A.

I want to create a text file C which contains (A-B) data.

So omit all the common lines .

The line in files are numeric data: like

```
id , some aspect, other aspec.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned, either way, whether or not your data can contain duplicate lines.  If it can, then be aware that Tim Pote's `sort`+`uniq` method **does not work** when there are unmatched duplicated lines in `A`. The `awk` and `comm` methods do work with duplicates in `A`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`uniq`](http://ss64.com/bash/uniq.html)

```
sort a b | uniq -u
```

If you want the lines that are the same between A and B, you can use `uniq -d`

```
sort a b | uniq -d
```

This assumes of course that the data in A and B are *exactly* the same.  There cannot be any lose spaces or tabs in the datasets.  If there are, you'll have to clean up the data with `sed`, `tr`, or `awk` first.

***Edit***

As Peter. O pointed out, this will fail if there happen to be exact duplicates in file `a`.  If that's an issue, you can fix it by doing this:

```
sort <(sort -u a) b | uniq -u
```

Comment: a very naive question. How do I save it in file "c"??

Comment: You need to redirect the output with `>`.  So the command would then be: `sort a b | uniq -u > c`

Answer (score 7):

There's a utility called [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) that's used for just this:

```
comm -23 A B > C
```

where `-2` means "reject the lines unique to file B" (you say there aren't any), and `-3` means "reject the lines common to both files".

@BartonChittenden makes a good point:

```
comm -23 <(sort A) <(sort B) > C
```

Comment: Note that both files must be sorted.

Comment: +1 for showing me `comm`, which I had never heard of.  +10 for showing me `<(command)` which I had also never heard of.

Comment: That's called "process substitution" and lets you treat the output of a command as if it's a file. see the man page.

Answer (score 4):

One way using `awk`. Redirect to save content in any file instead of `STDOUT`.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { data[ $0 ] = 1; next } FNR < NR { if ( $0 in data ) { next } print $0 }' fileB fileA
```

---

**UPDATED** with a more efficient command. Thanks to **Peter.O**:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{data[$0]; next}; $0 in data{next}; 1' fileB fileA
```

Comment: Just a few points to make it a bit more consise (and faster): 1) You do not need to assign a value to the array; just referring to it creates the index portion. 2) The second FNR test is not needed, as the preceding `next` caters for that. 3) The `if` test is superfluous, as `$0 in data` is a test in its own right. 4) Any non-zero value will cause `$0` to print, so the `print $0` can be a "boolean value":  `awk 'FNR==NR{data[$0]; next}; $0 in data{next}; 1' fileB fileA`

Comment: @Peter.O: Thank you for the suggestions. I adder your command to the answer.

Comment: You also don't need those null statements (trailing semi-colons) and rather than testing for $0 in data and doing next and then have an implicit print afterwards, you can just negate the test, and you don't need the first next (unless fileB is huge and efficiency is an issue) so you can just write it as `awk 'FNR==NR{data[$0]} !($0 in data}' fileB fileA`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a))' B A
```